# How to make text auto populate based off of cells in Excell

Tags: excel, text, formula

I am trying to make cell D4 auto populate with the text "N/A" based off of the the word "None" in C4. I can't seem to find anything anywhere else that is text specific.

Comment: `IF(C4="None",NA(),"")`

Comment: Or if you only want the text and not the error; `=IF(C4="None","N/A","")`